# Block WebBrowser Ads in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, block, ads

I need to block **ads** in my WebBrowser control... 
How can I do it using actually VB.NET or another program? I have heard about working with **hosts** file, maybe there any simple adblockers that work for or browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I think adblock is open source, perhaps look at working with it, get your head around it and you should be able to implement it fine :)

https://adblockplus.org/en/source

Comment: I don't have enough experience to do it (

Comment: What about hosts file? It's maybe better solution for me)

Comment: Editing hosts files.. its difficult to do correctly, and can break computers, but if youre wanting to do so, make your program copy the hosts file, paste in a temp location, edit it with whatever you need, and replace it, its simplier than it sounds :P Don't forget to ask them for admin or you're gunna have exceptions

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display a single page and don't want ads and don't mind handling the user input yourself (eg. kiosk), you can set:

```
webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = false;
webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
```